# Is there any map structure with key sorted by value?

Tags: java, data-structures

The TreeMap structure is a classic map structure with keys sorted by their natural order. For example, with the following codes:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
map.put("apple", 100);
map.put("orange", 10);
map.put("banana", 5);
```

If I want to print the map, like:

```
System.out.println(map);
```

Then the console will output (with natural order of the key):

{apple=100, banana=5, orange=10}

My question is: is there any Map structure available (UnknownMap) that could automatically sort the key by the value? If we have such structure, if we revise the codes to:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new UnknownMap<>();
map.put("apple", 100);
map.put("orange", 10);
map.put("banana", 5);
System.out.println(map);
```

The console will output:

{banana=5, orange=10, apple=100}

Note: this question is not asking how to sort a map. Instead, this is to ask a specific sorted map implementation that efficiently do the sorting by value with any changes to the map, such as put, remove, etc.

Comment: Please let me know if my question is not clear enough. Thanks!

Comment: You should probably read this: [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  It says, among othrer things, "Search, and research ...and keep track of what you find."  That's [more than a bit relevant here...](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+sorted+map)

Comment: @Joe That is not a duplicate.  **Sorting** a `Map` is not the same as a **sorted** `Map`.

Comment: @Joe, yeah, that could be a way to so. However, it is better to make automatically and efficiently sorting for the whole map with any insert, update, and remove.

Comment: There no any Map implementation in java which by default sort by Value. We need to do manual code to make them sort by value like by passing comparator (which sorts by value) to TreeMap constructor like `Map<K, V> sortedByValues = 
      new TreeMap<K, V>(valueComparator);`

Comment: @Andrew Henle, yes, it is more like a standalone map structure. Maybe, someone implemented it somewhere else, but is not available at Java.Util.

Comment: @NavnathJadhav, the comparator passed in `TreeMap` constructor is applied to keys anyway. [JavaDoc:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#TreeMap(java.util.Comparator)) `public TreeMap(Comparator<? super K> comparator)`
Constructs a new, empty tree map, ordered according to the given comparator. All keys inserted into the map must be _mutually comparable_ by the given comparator.

Comment: The solution is simply: `map.entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())`. But, if you need a mutable structure with efficient operations (add, delete, search, ...) both, on keys and value you are talking about a simple indexed database table with an additional indexed field (the value).

Comment: @AlexRudenko But we could build some logic to Sort Map by value like at https://beginnersbook.com/2014/07/how-to-sort-a-treemap-by-value-in-java

Comment: This is a duplicate of this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16545871/maintain-sortedmap-by-value

Answer (score 0):

Maintaining a sorted map by value is very not trivial, and would definitely require to adjust existing data structures. The `entries`, `keys` and `values` fields, that are required by the `Map` interface, are **expected** to be consistent with their order, and this is not trivial to get all of them sorted by value, and at least would require to override these fields in existing classes. Take for example the `TreeMap` class. The keys are stored in a tree data-structure, and the order of all three fields is according to the keys inserted to the tree. Also you cannot override the `Comparator of the tree to ignore the key itself, because some fundamental map properties of this class depends on that the tree compare between **keys** and not **values**.

This is as opposed to just sorting the map entries when it requires which is much simpler task. If you need to frequently use the sorted map entries, and the map tends to be modified between such usages, than it worth maintaining such data structure, otherwise you should just sort the entries and store them separately for future use.

In you you have decided to maintain the sorted map by value, you will probably need to implement it yourself. Try using the answers from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16545871/maintain-sortedmap-by-value) post